# Can a Mac boot when the right shift key is broken in the pressed position?

Tags: keyboard, terminal, macbook-pro

Here's the thing, the right shift key of my macbook is stuck, so it always boots in safe mode once I turn the machine on. Worse, I cannot log in since my password has lower case letters.

I tried resetting the NVRAM by holding Command - Option - P - R and also went into the disk utilities, however nothing I can do there helps.

I looking for a way to disable the right side shift key or alternatively enable the bluetooth via command line, since I have a wireless keyboard, but I cannot make either work.

UPDATE:

I woke up today and the key was working fine. However I do not trust on it. Probably when the MacBook gets warmer it will stuck again.

I downloaded a software called **KeyRemap4MacBook**, which can be downloaded from [here](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). I followed this [tutorial](http://www.quora.com/HOW-DO-I-TURN-OFF-MY-SHIFT-KEY) in order to deactive the key, this is a temporal fix while I make some saving to buy a new one.

Comment: Which model of macbook?  Was there a spill? Sticky-stuck?

Comment: it´s a macbook unibody 2009, and yes, already tried removing the key and cleaning and didn´t work.

Comment: Odd - I had thought that the system would detect a key that is held down but perhaps shift is special and not eligible for that. I have a bad answer, but need to look up the details...

Comment: Shift is special in that it forces the machine to boot into safe mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you might need to open the Mac and disconnect the keyboard.

Here is an image from iFixit.com's takeapart for the 15 inch model.

[image: keyboard ribbon cable to the logic board]

It is protected by a metal cage - but you won't need to do all the steps - just get the bottom off and disconnect the battery before working on the keyboard cable.

You will of course need a USB keyboard to work things temporarily and enable the bluetooth keyboard if you can't get there with a mouse or the trackpad only. Do read the cautions on the repair guide and be sure you are up to a delicate task. A proper Mac technician might charge $30 for this repair since it's quite easy for someone with all the tools and experience getting in to the Mac.

Comment: yes, I was thinking that problably this will be the way to go, I will comment my progress, thanks for your answer.

Comment: for some reason, I turned on my macbook this morning and now the right key is working fine... weird stuff, however I'm not likely to trust on it, I would like to disable it using a third party software, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any third-party software for this, as it won't load until after the system boots. Your only hope is to repair or disable the keyboard.