# I cant get past my password since my mac only spells caps and starts up in safe mode

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, safe-mode

In the morning two days ago, I spilled some water on my Macbook pro. It was shut down, so I dried it with a towel but that evening it worked perfectly.

I didn't use it for a day and this morning I started it up and it was in safe boot mode. I got past it by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, but I can't get past my password, because I have capitals that I can't disable.

I can't reset or remove it also because the commands won't work (for example,instead of "-" there's "_") and i can't reset it trought my apple ID.

Is it just that shift key is stuck?

Comment: Sounds like it. Try tapping it a lot (gently!) with the power off. If no joy give it a couple more days & try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Mac starts up in safeboot mode because of your SHIFT key pressed.

You could probably disconnect your keyboard as done [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75318/can-a-mac-boot-when-the-right-shift-key-is-broken-in-the-pressed-position?rq=1"iFixIt"), and try a bluetooth or USB keyboard.

In the answer with the repair instruction is also a programm mentioned, which can disable a specific key. Nevertheless, I wish good luck and hope you can fix it.

I found nice instructions on How-To-Detach-A-Key [here](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-remove-move-swap-replace-keys-mac-3462613/). It shows what you can expect when detaching a key from your keyboard.

** Update **

If you can `ssh` into your machine from another Mac, you could try to install `Karabiner`. With this app you can disable your left SHIFT key.

This app has a command line api, so 'fixing' your machine should be possible. Go [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/files/Karabiner-10.6.0.dmg"Download app") to download it.

Comment: I used another keyboard to get past my password and then Karabiner to disable my left SHIFT key (it was the one stuck) and use my fn key as SHIFT. It's all working perfectly.

Comment: I am glad, that my answer was helpful for you @Rikki . Would be nice, if you could mark my answer as the right one ;)